# Increment operator returns NaN

Tags: javascript, increment, nan, post-increment

I am trying to increment a variable using the `++` operator but I keep getting `NaN` as a result and I'm not sure why. Here is my code:

```
var wordCounts = { };
var x = 0
var compare = "groove is in the heart";
        var words = compare.split(/\b/);
        for(var i = 1; i < words.length; i++){
            if(words[i].length > 2){
                wordCounts["_" + words[i]]++;
            }
        }


alert(wordCounts.toSource());
```

Comment: The sample has an off-by-one error: the first index of `words` is 0, not 1. Also, should not "I" and "a" count as words? You can change the regexp so as to filter out the non-word characters, thus removing the need for the `words[i].length > 2` check. See if you can figure how.

Comment: yeah the 1 was me just trying stuff, actually I need to exclude any words less than 3 characters long and I'll also have to filter out the words "was" ,"the","and" words like that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The value of `wordCounts["_" + words[i]]` is initially `undefined` so when you ++ it, it gives you NaN. Just change your code to:

```
if (wordCounts["_" + words[i]]) {
    wordCounts["_" + words[i]]++;
} else {
    wordCounts["_" + words[i]] = 1;
}
```

Comment: Or `wordCounts["_" + words[i]] = (wordCounts["_" + words[i]] || 0) + 1;`

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to write it. Putting the key `"_" + words[i]` into a variable would also be a good idea for readability and a small optimization.

Comment: Yep. +1 for being first with both an explanation of the problem _and_ a solution.

Answer (score 2):

What you're basically doing is

`undefined++`

Which will result in...

`NaN`

Try...

`wordCounts["_" + words[i]] = (wordCounts["_" + words[i]]++ || 1);`

Since `NaN` is a "falsey" value the || will fall back to 1.

Comment: Please don't do `x = x++` type statements, they always lead to confusion. (In some languages - not sure about JS - the result is not even defined in the language spec.)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like...

```
var key = "_" + words[i];

if (wordCounts[key]) {
    wordCounts[key]++
} else {
    wordCounts[key] = 1;
}
```

You are trying to increment `undefined` which is giving you `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use the `++` operator (which takes a number and increments it by one) the target needs to have a number first.

Attempt a check to see if the object is defined, and if not initialize it by setting it's value to 1.

```
if ('undefined' === typeof wordCounts["_" + words[i]]) {
            wordCounts["_" + words[i]] = 0;
}
```

Something like:

```
var wordCounts = {};
var x = 0
var compare = "groove is in the heart";
var words = compare.split(/\b/);
for (var i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
    if ('undefined' === typeof wordCounts["_" + words[i]]) {
        wordCounts["_" + words[i]] = 0;
    }
    if (words[i].length > 2) {
        wordCounts["_" + words[i]]++;
    }
}
alert( JSON.stringify( wordCounts ) );
```

Comment: They do in some environments.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to increment an object (wordCounts[]++) it's not a number so it can't be incremented, which is why you're getting that error. What are you actually trying to do (in plain English)?

Comment: so how can i make this work since I don't know what the words are going to be

Comment: again, I'm asking that you ask a question using plain English syntax as to what  you're trying to accomplish here? What do you believe is stored in wordCounts[] and what do you expect to see happen when you increment (++) it? You say it's not "working" What would it be doing if it WAS working?